# Thymeleaf set default value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I am creating a input form for thymeleaf. I was wondering if there is a way to set a default value of null if nothing is entered into the text box and set that as the name?

I have tried doing:
th:value="${session.name}" and
value="null"

thanks in advance

Comment: Legend, Thanks xerx593 :)